# Unable to generate a new component

Tags: angular, components, angular-cli

When I type `new generate component component-name` in the `angular-cli`, it shows:

> Unable to find any apps in `angular-cli.json`.

What changes should I do?

Comment: How does your command look like? In what folder are in?

Comment: @Hinrich  The command I am using is 'ng generate component others'. I am in the src folder. So far I was working on the app.component.html, app.component.css, app.module.ts etc. Now I want to add another component.

Comment: I guess you have to be inside the folder with the `angular-cli.json` file to issue cli commands.

Comment: @Hinrich Thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change the current path of your cli to the root folder of your project. That is the folder with the `angular-cli.json` file. Issue all angular-cli commands from there.